# Create a dynamic Table out of JSON Object using Angular 5 directives

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, html-table

Is it possible to create a dynamic Table(dynamic Columns) based on a JSON object with Angular 5 directives/ Or with the help of jQuery? If so how?

Lets say i get this JSON response from a REST API:

```
{
      name: "Ferrari"
      country: "Italy",
      creater: "Enzo Ferrari"
      cars: [
        {
          modell: "Ferrari 488",
          price: "215.683€"
        },
        {
          modell: "Ferrari Portofino",
          price: "189.704€"
        }
     ]
    }
```

Now i want to create a Table out of this Data that should look like this:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------------+-------------+
| Name      | Country  | Creater      | Modell       | Price      | Modell             | Price       |
+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------+------------+----------------------------------+
|  Ferrari  | Italy    | Enzo Ferrarie| Ferrarie 488 | 189.704€   | Ferrarie Portofino | 189.704€    |
+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

What would the best approach be to solve this? I just cant figure it out how to solve this problem? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You can use [Angular Data Table](https://github.com/brunano21/angular-4-data-table) for this.

Comment: You can check a tutorial here: https://codeburst.io/display-a-table-using-components-with-angular-4-f13f0971666d
Or use an existing module with data tables implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one object in the table (meaning one header row and one data row) you could do something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Creater</th>
      <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="data.cars">
        <th>Modell</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </ng-template>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.country }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.creater }}</td>
      <ng-template ngFor let-car [ngForOf]="data.cars">
        <th>{{ car.modell }}</th>
        <th>{{ car.price }}</th>
      </ng-template>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

You can us ng-template and the ngFor directive to loop over the cars.

**Important:** If you have multiple data rows you need to make sure to transform your data so you always display the same amount of columns, otherwise the html will be broken.